# Can I amend one data sheet to match another data frame's ID that are almost similar?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, matching

I have multiple data frames to compare. My problem is the product IDs. one is set up like:

- 000-000-000-000
- Vs
- 000-000-000

(gross)

I have looked on here, reddit, YouTube, and even went deep down the rabbit hole trying .join,  .append, some other method I've never seen before, or even understand yet. Is there a way(or even better some documentation I can read on to learn this) to pull the Product ID from the Main excel sheet, compare it to the one(s) that should match. Then i will more than like make the in place ID across all sheets. That way I can use those IDs as the index and do a side by side compare of the ID to row data? Each ID has about 113 values to compare. That's 113 columns, but for each row if that make sense

Example: (colorful columns is main sheet that the non colored column will be compared to)
[image]

additional notes:
The highlighted yellow IDs are "unique", and I wont be changing those but instead write them to a list or something and use an if statement to ignore them when found.

Edit:
so I wrote this code which is almost perfect what I need to do with this.
It takes out the "-" which I apply to all my IDs. Just need to make a list of ID that are unique to skip over on taking away the zeros

```
dfSS["Product ID"] = dfSS["Product ID"].str.replace("-", "")
```

Then this will only list the digits up to 9 digits, except the unique IDs

```
dfSS["Product ID"] = dfSS["Product ID"]str[:9]
```

Will add the full code below here once i get it to work 100%

I am now trying to figure out how to say somethin like

```
lst =[1,2,3,4,5]
if dfSS["Product ID"] not in lst:
   dfSS["Product ID"] = dfSS["Product ID"].str.replace("-", "").str[:9]
```

This code does not work but everyday I get closer and closer to being able to compare these similar yet different data frames. the lst is just an example of a 000-000-000 Product IDs in a list that I do not want to filter at all. but keep in the data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID transformation is predictable, then one option is to use regex for homogenizing IDs. For example if the situation is just removing the first three digits, then something like the following can be used:

```py
df['short_id'] = df['long_id'].str.extract(r'\d\d\d-([\d-]*)')
```

If the ID transformation is not so predictable (e.g. due to transcription errors or some other noise in the data) then the best option is to first disambiguate the ID transformation using something like `recordlinkage`, see the example [here](https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/data_deduplication.html).

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll read through the documentation today and practice it tonight. I forgot about regex. Never really used it yet but i see that its quite popular. So now's my chance to get learn't lol

Comment: Not the exact RE used but this put me on the right track. Finally went deep into the RE world and no "RAGRATs" haha. Thanks again for your input

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved this for every Product ID with or without dashes, #, ltters, etc..

```
(\d\d\d-)?[_#\d-]?[a-zA-Z]?
```

(\d\d\d-)? -This is for the first & second three integer sets, w/ zero or more matches and a dashes (non-greedy)

[_#\d-]? - This is for any special chars and additional numbers (non-greedy)

[a-zA-Z]? - This, not sure why, but I had to separate from the last part due to it wouldn't pick up every letter. (non-greedy)

With the above I solved everything I needed for RE.

Where I learned how to improve my RE skills:

[RE Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

[Automate the Boring Stuff- Ch 7](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter7/)

[You can test you RE's here](https://pythex.org/)

Additional way to show this. Put this here to show there is no one way of doing it. RE is super awesome:

```
(\d{3}-)?[_#\d{3}-]?[a-zA-Z]?
```